# How do I install certificates using Octopus Deploy?

Tags: octopus-deploy

When deploying applications using Octopus Deploy, how do I include the SSL/TLS certificate?

Answer (score 1):

When deploying to Internet Information Services (IIS), the built-in Deploy to IIS step has the ability to include an SSL/TSL certificate variable and bind it to IIS when deployed.

The first step will be to add a certificate variable to your project.  Click on Variables and create a new variable.  Click on Change Type and select Certificate

[image]

Once you've added your variable, add the Deploy to IIS step to your project

[image]

Scroll down to the Bindings section and click the Add button

[image]

Choose HTTPS then select your certificate variable

[image]

And that's all!  When your application is deployed, it will also deploy the certificate to the server and bind it to port 443 in IIS!

Octopus Deploy also contains steps that will import certificates to Tomcat, Wildfly, or Java keystore.

[image]